# unbiased estimator Bernoulli variance

Tags: unbiased-estimator, bernoulli-distribution

Why do "most" (basically all) statistics text books use $\hat{\sigma}^2=\hat{p} (1-\hat{p})$ as an estimator for the variance of a Bernoulli process which we know is [biased](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2658035/is-the-point-estimate-for-variance-of-bernoulli-unbiased).
Should the default not be the bias corrected sample version $s^2 = \hat{p} (1-\hat{p}) \cdot n/(n-1)$, which is the default for non-binary data.

Comment: Bias is not the ultimate property to seek.  For instance, $s^2$ has a larger variance than $\hat\sigma^2$. (And all Bayes estimators are biased.)

Comment: While true, your answer applies to all estimators and does not address my specific question why for binary data alone we seem to prefer the biased variance ("1/n") when for all other cases, the default sample variance is chosen to be the unbiased version ("1/(n-1)").

Comment: I disagree with the closing of my question. None of the previous discussions addresses my very specific/narrow question as rephrased above. I am aware  of the general scientific discourse on unbiased estimators which skirts the difference in textbook defaults for Bernoulli versus "non Bernoulli" sample variance.